# SQL Server Multiple join return duplicated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates

I have 4 tables under my database TEST:

1. USER
2. USER_GROUP_PERMISSION
3. PERMISSION_TYPE
4. GROUPS

when I join the above tables using inner join and cross join instead of returning 520 rows it returns 2600 rows, most of the values duplicated

I need a final output without duplicates

Query:

```
select user.*
from TEST.USER user 
    inner join TEST.USER_GROUP_PERMISSION user_grp1
        on user.APPLICATION_ID = user_grp1.APPLICATION_ID 
    inner join TEST.PERMISSION_TYPE permission2_
        on user_grp1.PERMISSION_TYPE_ID = permission2_.PERMISSION_TYPE_ID
    inner join TEST.GROUPS groups
        on user_grp1.GROUP_ID = groups.GROUP_ID
    cross join TEST.PERMISSION_TYPE permission4_ 
where user_grp1.PERMISSION_TYPE_ID = permission4_.PERMISSION_TYPE_ID
    and groups.GROUP_ID in (101)
    and permission4_.PERMISSION_TYPE in (0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6)
    and user.NAME = 'ROBIN'
    and user.ACTIVE = '1'
order by upper(user.DISPLAY_VERSION) asc
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen if you `CROSS JOIN`? A `CROSS JOIN` "joins" every row in the existing dataset to every row in the joined table. If you are getting "duplicates" then your `ON` clauses, or `JOIN` types are wrong. But without sample data, expected results, or the logic you're trying to achieve we have no way of telling you what the correction is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show users without duplicates, then select from users only. Don't join! This is what the query should look like:

```
select * from users where ...
```

Your query is hard to understand, especially with the permission type joined twice, once even with an inner join disguised as a cross join. It looks like you want the user ROBIN provided he is active and his application has a group permission for group 101 and type 1 to 6. This would be:

```
select *
from test.user
where name = 'ROBIN'
and active = '1'
and application_id in
(
  select application_id
  from test.user_group_permission
  where group_id = 101
  and permission_type_id in 
  (
    select permission_type_id
    from test.permission_type
    where permission_type in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  )
)
order by upper(display_version);
```

(You can also join `permission_type` to `user_group_permission`, if you like that better than `IN`.)

Comment: It helps a lot, but still query taking more than 2.5 mins to run. it's a leading performance issue. Kindly suggest some ideas to resolve the performance

Comment: 2.5 minutes for one user??? This is weird. Query speed is almost always about indexes. As SQL Server seems to have issues with the query, I'd provide one index per table and permutation of its columns in question: two indexes on `permission_type` and the columns `permission_type` and `permission_type_id`, six indexes for `user_group_permission` with all permutations of `group_id`, `permission_type_id`, `application_id`, six indexes on `user` with `name`, `active`, `application_id`.

Comment: Example for the first two: `create index idx1 on permission_type (permission_type, permission_type_id);`, `create index idx2 on permission_type (permission_type_id, permission_type);`. When done, check which indexes are used and drop the others.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase the query using `exists`:

```
select user.*
from TEST.USER user 
where user.NAME = 'ROBIN'
      user.ACTIVE = '1' and
      exists (select 1
              from TEST.USER_GROUP_PERMISSION user_grp1 join
                   TEST.PERMISSION_TYPE permission2_
                   on user_grp1.PERMISSION_TYPE_ID = permission2_.PERMISSION_TYPE_ID join
                   TEST.GROUPS groups
                   on user_grp1.GROUP_ID = groups.GROUP_ID join 
                   TEST.PERMISSION_TYPE permission4_ 
                   on user_grp1.PERMISSION_TYPE_ID = permission4_.PERMISSION_TYPE_ID
              where user.APPLICATION_ID = user_grp1.APPLICATION_ID 
                    groups.GROUP_ID in (101) and
                    permission4_.PERMISSION_TYPE in (0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6)
       )
order by upper(user.DISPLAY_VERSION) asc
```

Then, the most important index for this is on `users(name, active, upper(DISPLAY_VERSION))`.